# How to easily append complex model and all its objects?

Tags: append

I downloaded a semi-truck .blend file from a sharing site and tried to add the semi-truck to my scene.

I used File -> Append and navigated to the truck .blend file and to the "objects" sub-folder.

The semi-truck is comprised of roughly 90 objects. Various shapes that make the bolts, mud-flaps, headlights...etc.

Is there a way to add everything that compromises the semi-truck into my scene all at once? I can't shift-click on the first and last objects listed to select everything in between. I can shift-click each individual object, but to do that 90 times to get the whole truck seems tedious and illogical.

Thanks

Comment: You can do that using python. What names does the 90 objects have without numbering?

Comment: Try appending as a group instead. If there isn't one created already open the truck file, group all relevant objects together, save, and then append the newly created group.

Comment: Alternately, box selecting with `B`, and selecting/deselecting everything with `A` still works in the file browser.